Pass plain string as an argument to a command in bash script
I am trying to write a simple bash script for package installation using zypper.
The script is supposed to read zypper package names line-by-line from packages.txt file, put them into an array and install them.
The only issue is that while it reads package names (strings) from the file correctly, it doesn't pass them into a command in a proper way.
Main bash script:
#!/bin/bash

#Force exit on ERR occurence
set -e

#Error handler to call on ERR occurence
error_handler(){
    echo "An error occured! Error code: $?"
}
trap "error_handler" ERR

#Function for retrieving package names as strings and invoking their installation using zypper
install_packages(){
    packages=()
    index=1
    #refresh repos
    echo -n "["$index"] Refreshing zypper repositories: "
    zypper -n refresh > /dev/null 2>&1
    echo 'OK'
    #read package names from file
    while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    packages+=("$line")
    done < "$1"

    #loop through packages() array and install them
    for line in "${packages[@]}"; do
        zypper -n install "$line"
    done
}
install_packages "./packages.txt"

Contents of "packages.txt file":
docker
docker-compose

Results of running the script:
[1] Refreshing zypper repositories: OK
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
' found.der of 'docker


a) shellcheck.net b) bash -x c) does your file have CRLF (a.k.a. Windows) line endings? the "found.der" line makes me believe it does (check with cat -A packages.txt)

one way to remove carriage returns: done < <(sed 's/\r$//' "$1")

See "Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?" and "Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?". In this case, you could get read to trim the carriage retuns with while IFS=$'\r' read ...

Why not readarray -t packages <"$1"?

Just use dos2unix packages.txt to fix the file before using it.

Do a xxd <<<$line to see, what is actually stored in the variable.
